# Rails accepts_nested_attributes_for unable to associate (or find) record passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, accepts-nested-attributes

Our Attachment model (in this case used for logos associated to teams) gets saved to the database before we associate it to the team. We do that because we do client side S3 uploading, so we need to generate an S3 key and confirm before we associate it with another model in the database.

The team model references the attachment class like this:

```rb
Class Team < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :logos, as: :attachable, class_name: "Attachment", dependent: :destroy, after_add: :cache_logo_url, inverse_of: :attachable
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :logos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Attachment class references polymorphic attachable like this:

```rb
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :attachable, polymorphic: true, optional: true
end
```

In the controller we accept the nested attributes:

```rb
class Api::V1::TeamsController < Api::V1::BaseController
  def update
    @team = Team.find(params[:id])
    authorize @team

    if @team.update(params)
      render status: :no_content
    else
      validation_error(@team.errors)
    end
  end

  private
  def team_params
    params.require(:team).permit(
      :name, 
      logos_attributes: [:id, :_destroy]
    )
  end
end
```

But when the PUT comes across, we get this:
[image]

Essentially, Rails can't find that attachment because the attachable is not set on attachment with id 1021.

What I want is for Rails to find the attachment based on ID (and only ID) and then associate it with the team.

Am I missing something obvious for how accepts nested attributes for should work in this case?

Comment: What version of Rails? Are you using ActiveStorage? How are you doing client side uploads? What does your controller code look like?

Comment: Also what is your form and upload code? As attachments are uploaded you need to append the info as form fields in the form. Are you creating an attachment record completely before you save the Team record? When I did this before ActiveRecord, I uploaded the file to S3 using Direct Upload in jquery, then on completion I added the id, file name, and the S3 file key to the form using JS.

Comment: Rails 6.1, not using ActiveStorage. In this case the upload is coming from a mobile app and this is a JSON controller endpoint. So the full lifecycle of the attachment happens out of band, before the app ever hits this endpoint.

Comment: Ok well that should simplify things but it's still impossible to guess at your code that you aren't showing us. Is Attachable something you wrote or a gem? Need to see more code. Can you attach something on the rails console using just ID?

Comment: Sure - I've added the full controller code and the models as well.

Comment: And does it work from the console? I don't see your API request so I don't know what params are actually being passed to the server. Can you include the full logs for the request cycle including where it shows the params passed to the endpoint? And please copy them from the console and paste them into your edit. The photo of console logs, while nicely colored is still a pain when they get large.  You should be seeing a params like `Parameters: {"team" => {"logo_attributes"=> {"logo_ids"=>[1,2,]...`

Comment: I'll dig up the logs again when I get back to it. That is how the params are being passed in (the standard nested attributes for, with ids as you describe). The issue is in that screenshot—Rails looks for that attachment by ID AND by attachable_type of the parent model. I want to force Rails to find the nested attributes for only by ID. I ended up doing some manual coding to get around it for now (extracted the _attributes params and associated the logos manually).

Answer (score 0):

Waiting on some more info, but in the meantime I think you might just want to pass the params like this:

```
params: {"teams"=>{logo_ids[1,2,3]}}
```

Rails should understand the passing of logo_ids since it has the has_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for in the model.

Rails understands `..._ids` in these contexts. So you should be able to say on the console:

```
@team.logo_ids = [1,2,3]
```

and it will do a lookup of those logos and attempt to attach them on save. You can also call `@team.logo_ids` and it will return an array of the attached logo ids.